# xamarin forms start nativ uwp page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

any idea how I can start a native UWP page from a Xamarin Forms page?
The reason why I'm asking:

I have a XF application that needs to start a UWP library after a click event. 
This library provides a special ORC reader. 
Therefore I created a dependency service to run the platform specific function. 
What I need now, is to open that UWP page, that contains the "Camera stream" to show the user what he is currently scanning. 
And this is where I am hanging at the moment.

In my class that is called from the dep. service, I 
         myPage mp = new myPage();

But how can I show the new page?

Frame fr = Window.Current.Content as Frame gives me the error, that this page cannot be converted from a XF Frame to a Window Frame.

Or is there generally another way to handle this? Some advice would be great.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a custom renderer.

Create a new OcrView class in your shared project inherited from View.

Place it on your Xamarin Forms XAML page.

Handle the OCR component in the UWP renderer.

Have a look at the Implementing a View section on [this custom renderer overview](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/)

Comment: Ah ok, glad that there is no "that's not possible, WTF are you thinking..." :). Thanks for your answer, I will check this and let you know if it works for me.

Comment: unfortunately, I'm not getting closer. Is custom render really the way to go? This can be used to use native controls. But to start or render a platform specific page? Hmm... I'm nor sure how to start.

Comment: Did you look at the implementing a view section? It shows how to implement a new view that displays a camera preview and how to implement it via a custom renderer on UWP. I would have thought this was very similar to your use case.

Comment: ok, I tried it with pagerender -> that seems to be what I need.